# Shared libraries C++ Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation, shared-libraries

I need to compile fat binary file to be able use it on another linux machine. But there are some libraries missing so as I understand I should compile it with some -shared options. But I don't understand how to configure a Makefile for that. Currently my makefile looks like this:

```
CC = g++
CC_FLAGS = -std=c++11 -O2 -static -Wall

EXEC = cpp_server
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
LIBS = -lpthread -lmicrohttpd -lz

$(EXEC): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $(EXEC) $(LIBS)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CC_FLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(EXEC) $(OBJECTS)
```

Comment: BTW, you might find [libonion](http://coralbits.com/libonion/) (or [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt)....) easier to use than  `-lmicrohttpd` if you want some HTTP server library

Comment: Well it's already working, but I need to compile this library into my binary file to be able execute it on computer where that library is not installed

Comment: Notice that [fat binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_binary) has a *specific* meaning, which is not the one you want. So just speak of a binary (or a statically linked binary).

Comment: In general, you cannot do something with Make if you don't know how to do it *without* Make. You must figure out how to build the binary using the command line, before you worry about wrapping the technique in a makefile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll better take advantage of the many built-in rules of GNU make. Run once `make -p` to learn them. So you should use `CXX` instead of `CC` and replace `CC_FLAGS` with `CXXFLAGS`.

You may want to build a statically linked executable. Then you should pass `-static` into your *linking* command, using `LINKFLAGS`

So try with

```
## untested Makefile for GNU make
# variables known to make
CXX= g++
CXXFLAGS= -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -Wextra
LINKFLAGS= -static
LIBS= -lpthread -lmicrohttpd -lz
# this project needs:
MYEXEC= cpp_server
MYSOURCES= $(wildcard *.cpp)
MYOBJECTS= $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
.PHONY: all clean

all: $(MYEXEC)
$(MYEXEC): $(MYOBJECTS)
   $(LINK.cc) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
clean:
   rm -f $(MYEXEC) $(MYOBJECTS)
```

AFAIK you don't need anything more in your `Makefile` (provided you  use a GNU `make`, not e.g. a BSD one). Of course you need appropriate <kbd>TAB</kbd> characters in your `Makefile` (so you need to use some editor able to insert them).

You could want to statically link only `-lmicrohttpd` (and dynamically link the other libraries; however, you might want to also statically link the C++ standard library, which depends upon the compiler and could change when the compiler changes; linking also the C++ library statically is left as an exercise). You could do that with removing the `LINKFLAGS` line and using

```
LIBS= -Bstatic -lmicrohttpd -Bdynamic -lz -lpthread
```

BTW the `-shared` linker option is need to *build* from [position-independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) object files a shared library (not to *use* one). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23134086/841108) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14093902/841108).

You may want to use `make --trace` (or `remake -x`, using [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/)) to debug your `Makefile`

If you want to understand what actual files are linked, add `-v -Wl,--verbose` to `LINKFLAGS` perhaps by running `make 'LINKFLAGS=-v -Wl,--verbose'` on your terminal.

You might want to `make clean` before anything else.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But now I have:Makefile:15: *** missing separator.  Stop.

Comment: If I understand correctly and I have libmicrohttpd under /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmicrohttpd.so.10. How should I run make command?

Comment: Then you don't have a static form of that library, and you probably need to recompile it from source. You surely want to use `libmicrohttpd.a` (not some `libmicrohttpd.so.10` which is a *shared* library, not a *static* one)

Comment: I also have libmicrohttpd.a on the same path, but how can I tell compiler to use that?

Comment: Did you try my last `LIBS=` line with `-Bstatic -lmicrohttpd -Bdynamic`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am using the same makefile but it does not compile the source files. I will of course ask it as a separate question.

Comment: Don't forget to do a `make clean` or at least `rm *.o`